# How to number the rows in MUI X Datagrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

~ Using MUIx v5.17.4. (2022)

I want to have a table that looks like this:

[image]

You can achieve that simply by using the `row` prop of the `<DataGrid />` component, see the following example:

```js
const columns = [ {field: 'No.'}, {field: 'Header 1'}, {field: 'Header 2'} ]
const rows = users.map((user, i)=> ({ 'No.': i + 1, ...user }))
```

Where `users` is a list (array) coming from some back-end.

However,

Using this method, if you changed the sort of the items, the "No." field will **not** always count in sequence: i.e., 1,2,3,4 or 4,3,2,1.
Instead, it would have a sequence like 4,2,1,3 if you change the **sorting** or **filtering** options.

I want the sequence to be always in order, i.e, either 1,2,3,4 or 4,3,2,1.

Can you help me please, as I couldn't find an example explaining that.

Comment: Do you also want this new column (`No.`) to be sortable? If so, I don't think it's feasible.

Comment: @AhmetEmreKilinc, No